# Distance from a sphere to a plane

Tags: calculus

If I have a sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$ and a plane $ax + by + cz = k$,
how do I find the distance between them?

This is what I have so far and I'm right.
Let C be the centre of the sphere, (0,0,0) and the $\vec{n}=\langle a,b,c\rangle$.
The equation of the line from C to a point on the plane P that is perpendicular to the plane is $x=at, y=bt, z=ct$.
So I substitute these equations into $ax + by + cz = k$.

$a(at)+b(bt)+c(ct)=k \\
=a^2t+b^2t+c^2t=k \\
=t(a^2+b^2+c^2)=k \\
t\Vert \vec{CP} \Vert^2=k$

Is this correct so far. I also know that I have to subtract $R^2$ from it but not sure really where to go from here, what actually the k represents in this instance.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try this  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424125/shortest-distance-from-a-point-to-a-plane?rq=1

Comment: Shouldn't that be $ax+by+cz=k$ instead?

Comment: Yeah I think you're right Michael. In my case, yes.

Comment: Thanks Santosh, that was helpful too.

Comment: You can use the distance from a point to a plane (e.g. formula 9 [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html)) and subtract the radius.

Comment: Have a look at this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128416/how-to-find-the-point-on-the-sphere-that-is-closest-to-a-plane/2143578#2143578

Comment: Thanks Pete, J.M. that's actually the page that i based my solution on via researching Sonnhard's post. Thanks for responding too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Without loss of generality we may assume that $k\geq 0$. You've started in $CP=t\vec n$ and arrived in $t=k/\|\vec n\|^2$.  Hence 
$CP=\frac{k}{\|\vec n\|^2}\vec n$.  It's length is $k/\|\vec n\|$, which is the plane's distance from the origin.

Comment: I dont think i'm following you Mick. from my work $x=at$ for instance. So I put t=\frac{k}{\Vert vec{b}\Vert^2 into this, and then put x,y,and z into my plane formula?

Comment: @Bucephalus See my edit, please.

Comment: AM trying to understand what you're saying here Michael. Substitute $t=k/\|\vec n\|^2$ into x=at, y=bt, and z=ct, and then into the plane's equation?

Comment: OH yeah, very nice. So then the final answer would be $\frac{k}{\Vert \vec{n} \Vert^2}-R^2$. Because I wan the distance from the surface of the sphere to the plane. Well that's good because that gives me the same answer I came up with using Sonnhard's tip. Thanks for helping me complete my original post. Dave.

Comment: What does WLOG stand for?

Comment: No, it would be $\frac{k}{\|\vec n\|}-R$, if that value is positive and zero otherwise.

Comment: Without Loss Of Generality.

Comment: Of course, $R$ not $R^2$, cheers.

Comment: And $\|\vec n\|$ instead of $\|\vec n\|^2$.

Comment: Sorry, racing through an assignment. On my last problem.

Answer (score 0):

use the so called Hessian Normalform of the given plane
$$\frac{ax+by+cz-k}{\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}=0$$
and plugging the coordinates $$x=0,y=0,z=0$$

Comment: Thanks Sonnhard, that's very helpful

Comment: with this equation it is very easy to solve some Problems in Geometry, thank you!